# How to write a Django model iterator?

Tags: django-models, iterator

I wrote a small Django app to handle user private messages. The model looks like:

```
#models.py
class Message(models.Model):
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    body = models.TextField()
    from = models.ForeignKey(User)
    to = models.ForeignKey(User)
    #.... some more fields
```

I want to add an "Inbox" property/method to the model to encapsulate querying the DB for the inbox items, so in *views.py* I could iterate through the received messages like this:

```
# views.py
from models import Message

for msg in Message.inbox(request.user):
    print "%s: %s", (msg.from, msg.subject)
```

So obviously I should do something like `qs = Message.objects.filter(to=user)` within the model class, but how do I do it? What do I return? Is it a good idea at all, or a bad one?

Comment: why cant you just return the QuerySet?

Comment: @AaronGage, returning the QuerySet is the default solution. However, I am looking for a more elegant way of creating an iterator in the model class.

Comment: @user1102018 What's inelegant about a queryset?

Comment: @Marcin, nothing is inelegant in a QuerySet. As I wrote, I'm looking for a MORE elegant way :) If this is an acceptable and good practice method, then I will look no further.

Comment: @user1102018 We can't quantify "more elegant" if you don't say what you find to be the shortcomings of your existing solution.